# How to use win32com module in Jython

Tags: java, jython, win32com

I have some codes of python that convers word file to html file, it uses win32com module, like this

```
from win32com import client as wc
```

I hoped to invoke python program in java codes, so I used Jython.
But Jython don't recognition win32com module, throws exception like this

```
ImportError: No module named win32com
```

I searched some information in internet, someone says
"The problem is that the win32api module is implemented in C so it is not available from Jython."
see also http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.jython.user/1371

Will you please tell me how to use win32com module in Jython?

---

I tried to convert Word files that include math formula to HTML with [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org), 
but always doesn't work well. 
So I have to use python and win32com module, 
because it can convert math formulas to images like Microsoft Office Word does. 
Does anyone have any suggestions about converting math formulas in Word filse with POI?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will you please tell me how to use win32com module in Jython?

You can't and you stated the reason yourself. Win32com module is written in C. Jython contains all the modules that are originally written in Python, but (Java translations of) only few of the CPython modules that are originally written in native code. Win32com module is not included.

I think Jython's idea is to be pure Java, and interoperation with Microsoft COM modules can't be done in pure Java. It *could* in principle be implemented using JNI and lots of work, but hasn't been done.

If your goal is to convert Word files to HTML, using Java, have a look at [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer. I know Apache POI, I try to convert Word files that include math formula to HTML with POI, it always doesn't work well. I have to use python and win32com module, because it can convert math formulas to images like Microsoft Office Word does. Do you have any advice about converting math formulas in Word filse with POI?

Comment: @RonQi: I don't have experience of formulas/Word/POI combination. I can imagine it can be hairy, good luck...